# How to use a password as an external variable in shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script, mysql

I have this MySQL backup script that I use to back up MySQL databases. Very useful, and it runs on fixed intervals using a cron. However, I need somehow provide this script with the MySQL password. This password is not the same on every server, but as I manage several servers, this particular script is part of a git-controlled repository that is synced together with some other scripts occasionally. Now, my question is: how can I use this same script as part of a git repo, if the password is different? The solution I can come up with is defining the password as an external/global variable in shell, rather than in the script itself, and that way my script can remain the same on every server. However, I am not sure what the proper way is to do so, nor am I sure if this is a good idea (security/best practices-wise).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least keeping passwords in git is surely a bad idea.

It'd be better using .config file for that. Also it's neat to have some .config-example added to git but with different extension and not real passwords of course — it allows for synchronizing changes regarding to those variables in code and config, also such .config-example can be used as starting point for new installation, for e. g..